# Пути к файлам заголовком (CLion, C++)

Tags: c++, clion, пути

Подскажите, пожалуйста, не очень соображаю: как можно задать пути к директориям, в которых хранятся файлы заголовком. Относительные пути в cpp файлах использовать очень неудобно (особенно при моей архитектуре). Я и не пойму: это задается для компилятора с помощью того же cmake, либо для IDE в настройках IDE.

Ну, небольшой пример:

- include
  -- mine.h
- src
  -- mine.cpp

Использовать в mine.cpp строку следующего вида очень неудобно:

```
#include "../include/mine.h"
```

Хотелось бы разом дать понять системе, что все файлы заголовков стоит искать в "../include/". И я тогда, соответственно, смогу просто использовать:

```
#include "mine.h"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

нужно поставить

```
target_include_directories(TARGET foo include)
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html